# What URL manipulation is better to use in Yii framework

Tags: php, url, redirect, yii

I was wandering which solution is better to use in Yii framework,

1) Redirecting page from somethingController.php

```
$this->redirect(array($this->id."/something"));
```

|| or

2) Creating Url

```
$this->createUrl($this->id."/something");
```

in view using contoroller & action you need.

Or maybe there is a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. The two examples you gave are for different things. One redirects to another action, the other creates a URL.

Comment: sorry my bad. i change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It like ask `what is better miles or pounds?`. That functions are very different.

You need to use `redirect` when need to change page without user action in some conditions, for example in **controller**:

```
if($money==0)
{
    $this->redirect(array('alerts/notEnoughMoney'));
}
```

If you want to generate address what will used for example in **html links**, then you need to use `createUrl`, because it will:

- Avoid unnecessary step with redirect
- Better for SEO, and will be more user friendly
- Better for customizing

You can use `createUrl` in **view**, for example:

```
<?php
$link = $this->createUrl(array('user/profile'));
?>

<a href="<?php echo $link ?>">My Profile</a>
```

In any case, if you using redirects what visible for **search bots** you need to add second parameter:

```
$this->redirect(array('alerts/notEnoughMoney'),301);
----------------------------------------------^^^^
```

With this parameter bot will understand what this next page is permanent and will cache it as "main".

Comment: Thank you very much, i know my question is "miles & pounds", but it's all new to me, & I'm trying to understand it, thanks once again, you helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->createUrl($this->id."/".$this->action->id);
```

is the better because it will work with URL manager also and give rewrite urls.